# ListView single Choice adapt to size of item

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` which has a single choice. I placed an add function for it. My code is:

```
public void add(){
    String name = (allergytxt.getText().toString() + "\n" +
                   desctxt.getText().toString() + "\n" +
                   doctxt.getText().toString() + "\n" +
                   notxt.getText().toString());

    if (!name.isEmpty() && name.length() > 0) {
        adapter.add(name);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        allergytxt.setText("");
        desctxt.setText("");
        doctxt.setText("");
        notxt.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Apparently the listview would only display 2 lines of text. Heeeelp. (I'm new to androdid studio and java by the way)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is to create a custom adapter to give you more control over the layout of each row.

By default an adapter returns a simple TextView as a row. In the event that you want a more complicated layout row for your ListView, you need a custom adapter. Seems like a tedious process at first but you'll get used to it. [This Tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter) really helped me the first time I tried. Also look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788776/android-how-to-create-a-multiline-list-view) answer. Happy coding!